# GStreamer USB camera H264 pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, yocto, openembedded, imx8

I'm running into issues creating a GStreamer pipeline that takes the frames from the USB video camera connected to my embedded Linux (slightly modified Toradex Multimedia image) development board. I'm able to display the camera's feed using the following pipeline

`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! v4l2jpegdec ! autovideosink`

However, if I try to do a simple h264 encoding, I get the following error (full log below). From what I can tell, the caps from the jpegdecoder are properly matched to the ones needed by h264 encoder. I've had to cut the log file, but the last line shows the error and I've removed the GST_STATES events as those didn't seem to show anything meaningful.

```
root@apalis-imx8-06959030:~# GST_DEBUG=4 gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! v4l2jpegdec ! v4l2h264enc ! v4l2h264dec ! autovideosink
0:00:00.000155372  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:586:init_pre: Initializing GStreamer Core Library version 1.16.2
0:00:00.000230120  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:587:init_pre: Using library installed in /usr/lib
0:00:00.000263869  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:605:init_pre: Linux apalis-imx8-06959030 5.4.154-5.5.0-devel+git.c65f1622951c #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 3 15:58:01 UTC 2022 aarch64
0:00:00.000773982  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_INIT gstmessage.c:128:_priv_gst_message_initialize: init messages
0:00:00.001962580  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_INIT gstcontext.c:84:_priv_gst_context_initialize: init contexts
0:00:00.002429820  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:318:_priv_gst_plugin_initialize: registering 0 static plugins
0:00:00.002664189  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:226:gst_plugin_register_static: registered static plugin "staticelements"
0:00:00.002700188  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:228:gst_plugin_register_static: added static plugin "staticelements", result: 1
0:00:00.002752687  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1720:ensure_current_registry: reading registry cache: /home/root/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.aarch64.bin
0:00:00.061302350  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistrybinary.c:621:priv_gst_registry_binary_read_cache: loaded /home/root/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.aarch64.bin in 0.058444 seconds
0:00:00.061605218  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1579:scan_and_update_registry: Validating plugins from registry cache: /home/root/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.aarch64.bin
0:00:00.072084354  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1678:scan_and_update_registry: Registry cache has not changed
0:00:00.072151228  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO            GST_REGISTRY gstregistry.c:1755:ensure_current_registry: registry reading and updating done, result = 1
0:00:00.072186227  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:806:init_post: GLib runtime version: 2.62.6
0:00:00.072219726  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:808:init_post: GLib headers version: 2.62.6
0:00:00.072244726  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_INIT gst.c:810:init_post: initialized GStreamer successfully
0:00:00.072309849  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO            GST_PIPELINE gstparse.c:336:gst_parse_launch_full: parsing pipeline description 'v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! v4l2jpegdec ! v4l2h264enc ! v4l2h264dec ! autovideosink '
0:00:00.467121835  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:902:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: plugin "/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideo4linux2.so" loaded
(...)
0:00:00.481494256  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1579:gst_event_new_reconfigure: creating reconfigure event
0:00:00.481706377  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:361:gst_element_factory_create: creating element "pipeline"
0:00:00.482190866  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO            GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:648:gst_parse_perform_link: linking some pad of GstV4l2Src named v4l2src0 to some pad of v4l2jpegdec named v4l2jpegdec0 (0/0) with caps "(NULL)"
0:00:00.482276239  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1771:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element v4l2src0:(any) to element v4l2jpegdec0:(any)
0:00:00.482360987  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1034:gst_pad_check_link: trying to link v4l2src0:src and v4l2jpegdec0:sink
0:00:00.482480984  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4237:gst_pad_peer_query:<v4l2jpegdec0:src> pad has no peer
0:00:00.482790977  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1587:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: v4l2src0 and v4l2jpegdec0 in same bin, no need for ghost pads
0:00:00.482910974  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2377:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link v4l2src0:src and v4l2jpegdec0:sink
0:00:00.483005222  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4237:gst_pad_peer_query:<v4l2jpegdec0:src> pad has no peer
0:00:00.483142969  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2585:gst_pad_link_full: linked v4l2src0:src and v4l2jpegdec0:sink, successful
0:00:00.483202092  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1579:gst_event_new_reconfigure: creating reconfigure event
0:00:00.483260716  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstpad.c:5812:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<v4l2src0:src> Received event on flushing pad. Discarding
0:00:00.483383338  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO            GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:648:gst_parse_perform_link: linking some pad of v4l2jpegdec named v4l2jpegdec0 to some pad of v4l2h264enc named v4l2h264enc0 (0/0) with caps "(NULL)"
0:00:00.483459962  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1771:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element v4l2jpegdec0:(any) to element v4l2h264enc0:(any)
0:00:00.483539335  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1034:gst_pad_check_link: trying to link v4l2jpegdec0:src and v4l2h264enc0:sink
0:00:00.483655457  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1587:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: v4l2jpegdec0 and v4l2h264enc0 in same bin, no need for ghost pads
0:00:00.483887827  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2377:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link v4l2jpegdec0:src and v4l2h264enc0:sink
0:00:00.484000449  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2585:gst_pad_link_full: linked v4l2jpegdec0:src and v4l2h264enc0:sink, successful
0:00:00.484058573  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1579:gst_event_new_reconfigure: creating reconfigure event
0:00:00.484117697  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstpad.c:5812:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<v4l2jpegdec0:src> Received event on flushing pad. Discarding
0:00:00.484235569  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO            GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:648:gst_parse_perform_link: linking some pad of v4l2h264enc named v4l2h264enc0 to some pad of v4l2h264dec named v4l2h264dec0 (0/0) with caps "(NULL)"
0:00:00.484312192  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1771:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element v4l2h264enc0:(any) to element v4l2h264dec0:(any)
0:00:00.484390940  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1034:gst_pad_check_link: trying to link v4l2h264enc0:src and v4l2h264dec0:sink
0:00:00.484480938  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4237:gst_pad_peer_query:<v4l2h264dec0:src> pad has no peer
0:00:00.484623560  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1587:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: v4l2h264enc0 and v4l2h264dec0 in same bin, no need for ghost pads
0:00:00.484713933  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2377:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link v4l2h264enc0:src and v4l2h264dec0:sink
0:00:00.484800306  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4237:gst_pad_peer_query:<v4l2h264dec0:src> pad has no peer
0:00:00.485071675  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2585:gst_pad_link_full: linked v4l2h264enc0:src and v4l2h264dec0:sink, successful
0:00:00.485132173  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1579:gst_event_new_reconfigure: creating reconfigure event
0:00:00.485191047  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstpad.c:5812:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<v4l2h264enc0:src> Received event on flushing pad. Discarding
0:00:00.485305419  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO            GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:648:gst_parse_perform_link: linking some pad of v4l2h264dec named v4l2h264dec0 to some pad of GstAutoVideoSink named autovideosink0 (0/0) with caps "(NULL)"
0:00:00.485444541  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1771:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element v4l2h264dec0:(any) to element autovideosink0:(any)
0:00:00.485525289  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1034:gst_pad_check_link: trying to link v4l2h264dec0:src and autovideosink0:sink
0:00:00.485644037  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstutils.c:1587:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: v4l2h264dec0 and autovideosink0 in same bin, no need for ghost pads
0:00:00.485734785  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2377:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link v4l2h264dec0:src and autovideosink0:sink
0:00:00.485854907  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2585:gst_pad_link_full: linked v4l2h264dec0:src and autovideosink0:sink, successful
0:00:00.486087902  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1579:gst_event_new_reconfigure: creating reconfigure event
0:00:00.486152900  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstpad.c:5812:gst_pad_send_event_unchecked:<v4l2h264dec0:src> Received event on flushing pad. Discarding
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
(...)
0:00:00.489583697  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstpad.c:2132:gst_pad_unlink: unlinking sink:proxypad0(0xaaaadc6260f0) and fake-video-sink:sink(0xaaaadc619220)
0:00:00.489664070  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstpad.c:2187:gst_pad_unlink: unlinked sink:proxypad0 and fake-video-sink:sink
0:00:00.489733818  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO           GST_PARENTAGE gstbin.c:1801:gst_bin_remove_func:<autovideosink0> removed child "fake-video-sink"
0:00:00.489839816  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO         GST_REFCOUNTING gstelement.c:3251:gst_element_dispose:<fake-video-sink> 0xaaaadc62e5f0 dispose
0:00:00.489907189  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:784:gst_element_remove_pad:<fake-video-sink> removing pad 'sink'
0:00:00.489997937  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO         GST_REFCOUNTING gstelement.c:3296:gst_element_dispose:<fake-video-sink> 0xaaaadc62e5f0 parent class dispose
0:00:00.490067936  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO         GST_REFCOUNTING gstelement.c:3328:gst_element_finalize:<fake-video-sink> 0xaaaadc62e5f0 finalize
0:00:00.490137059  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO         GST_REFCOUNTING gstelement.c:3333:gst_element_finalize:<fake-video-sink> 0xaaaadc62e5f0 finalize parent
0:00:00.497457767  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:902:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: plugin "/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstwaylandsink.so" loaded
0:00:00.497574014  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:358:gst_element_factory_create: creating element "waylandsink" named "autovideosink0-actual-sink-wayland"
0:00:00.498246374  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:668:gst_element_add_pad:<GstBaseSink@0xaaaadc6343e0> adding pad 'sink'
0:00:00.498384371  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:915:gst_element_get_static_pad: found pad autovideosink0-actual-sink-wayland:sink
0:00:00.498631115  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4237:gst_pad_peer_query:<autovideosink0-actual-sink-wayland:sink> pad has no peer
(...)
0:00:00.502424154  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2377:gst_pad_link_prepare: trying to link sink:proxypad0 and autovideosink0-actual-sink-wayland:sink
0:00:00.502562400  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:2585:gst_pad_link_full: linked sink:proxypad0 and autovideosink0-actual-sink-wayland:sink, successful
0:00:00.502604774  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1579:gst_event_new_reconfigure: creating reconfigure event
(...)
0:00:00.505876325  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 v4l2_calls.c:629:gst_v4l2_open:<v4l2h264dec0:sink> Opened device 'vpu B0' (/dev/video12) successfully
0:00:00.505952323  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 v4l2_calls.c:735:gst_v4l2_dup:<v4l2h264dec0:src> Cloned device 'vpu B0' (/dev/video12) successfully
0:00:00.506098070  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1228:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink> got 15 format(s):
0:00:00.506149818  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   JPEG
0:00:00.506196067  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   M264
0:00:00.506241816  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   LOGO
0:00:00.506286440  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   XVID
0:00:00.506331439  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   HEVC
0:00:00.506375813  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   VP80
0:00:00.506420312  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   H263
0:00:00.506464436  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   SPK0
0:00:00.506509060  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   VP60
0:00:00.506552434  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   MPG4
0:00:00.506596183  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   AVS0
0:00:00.506639932  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   MPG2
0:00:00.506683931  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   VC1L
0:00:00.506727930  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   VC1G
0:00:00.506771929  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264dec0:sink>   H264
0:00:00.506953050  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2031:gst_v4l2_object_get_interlace_mode: Driver bug detected - check driver with v4l2-compliance from http://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git

0:00:00.506999299  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2031:gst_v4l2_object_get_interlace_mode: Driver bug detected - check driver with v4l2-compliance from http://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git

0:00:00.507306667  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4458:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2h264dec0:sink> probed caps: video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], height=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], colorimetry=(string){ bt709 }, parsed=(boolean)true
(...)
0:00:00.508503890  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 v4l2_calls.c:629:gst_v4l2_open:<v4l2h264enc0:sink> Opened device 'vpu encoder' (/dev/video13) successfully
0:00:00.508571513  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 v4l2_calls.c:735:gst_v4l2_dup:<v4l2h264enc0:src> Cloned device 'vpu encoder' (/dev/video13) successfully
(...)
0:00:00.509007878  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4458:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2h264enc0:sink> probed caps: video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)[ 64, 1920, 16 ], height=(int)[ 48, 1920, 2 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/65535, 65535/1 ], interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string){ bt709 }
0:00:00.509067877  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1228:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264enc0:src> got 1 format(s):
0:00:00.509114876  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2h264enc0:src>   H264
0:00:00.509377245  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4400:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2h264enc0:src> Failed to probe pixel aspect ratio with VIDIOC_CROPCAP: Invalid argument
0:00:00.509608489  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4458:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2h264enc0:src> probed caps: video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, width=(int)[ 64, 1920, 16 ], height=(int)[ 48, 1920, 2 ], colorimetry=(string){ bt709 }, framerate=(fraction)[ 1/65535, 65535/1 ]
(...)
0:00:00.510477970  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 v4l2_calls.c:629:gst_v4l2_open:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink> Opened device 'vpu B0' (/dev/video12) successfully
0:00:00.510546718  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 v4l2_calls.c:735:gst_v4l2_dup:<v4l2jpegdec0:src> Cloned device 'vpu B0' (/dev/video12) successfully
0:00:00.510673340  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1228:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink> got 15 format(s):
0:00:00.510722464  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   JPEG
0:00:00.510768588  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   M264
0:00:00.510813712  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   LOGO
0:00:00.510858211  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   XVID
0:00:00.510902960  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   HEVC
0:00:00.510947459  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   VP80
0:00:00.510991958  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   H263
0:00:00.511036582  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   SPK0
0:00:00.511081206  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   VP60
0:00:00.511125705  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   MPG4
0:00:00.511171204  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   AVS0
0:00:00.511215578  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   MPG2
0:00:00.511259577  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   VC1L
0:00:00.511304201  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   VC1G
0:00:00.511348325  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink>   H264
0:00:00.511400699  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2031:gst_v4l2_object_get_interlace_mode: Driver bug detected - check driver with v4l2-compliance from http://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git

0:00:00.511442573  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:2031:gst_v4l2_object_get_interlace_mode: Driver bug detected - check driver with v4l2-compliance from http://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git

0:00:00.511664318  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4458:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink> probed caps: image/jpeg, width=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], height=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], colorimetry=(string){ bt709 }, parsed=(boolean)true
(...)
0:00:00.512338052  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    v4l2 v4l2_calls.c:629:gst_v4l2_open:<v4l2src0:src> Opened device 'HD USB Camera: HD USB Camera' (/dev/video2) successfully
0:00:00.512379801  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 WARN                    v4l2 v4l2_calls.c:547:gst_v4l2_subscribe_event:<v4l2src0> Cannot subscribe V4L2_EVENT_SOURCE_CHANGE or V4L2_EVENT_EOS event for device '/dev/video2'.
(....)
0:00:00.513800894  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:1373:gst_base_src_do_seek:<v4l2src0> seeking: time segment start=0:00:00.000000000, offset=0:00:00.000000000, stop=99:99:99.999999999, rate=1.000000, applied_rate=1.000000, flags=0x00, time=0:00:00.000000000, base=0:00:00.000000000, position 0:00:00.000000000, duration 99:99:99.999999999
0:00:00.513879142  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                    task gsttask.c:453:gst_task_set_lock: setting stream lock 0xaaaadc618260 on task 0xaaaadc61a4d0
0:00:00.513916641  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:6159:gst_pad_start_task:<v4l2src0:src> created task 0xaaaadc61a4d0
(...)
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
0:00:00.515688101  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:1449:gst_event_new_latency: creating latency event 0:00:00.000000000
0:00:00.515772099  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO                     bin gstbin.c:2783:gst_bin_do_latency_func:<pipeline0> configured latency of 0:00:00.000000000
0:00:00.515842472  2492 0xaaaadc3bf600 INFO              GST_STATES gstbin.c:2503:gst_bin_element_set_state:<autovideosink0> current READY pending PAUSED, desired next PLAYING
(...)
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.517009446  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO        GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:912:gst_element_get_static_pad: no such pad 'sink' in element "v4l2src0"
0:00:00.517236565  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1228:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2src0:src> got 1 format(s):
0:00:00.517279814  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2src0:src>   MJPG
0:00:00.517487060  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4458:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2src0:src> probed caps: image/jpeg, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)60/1; image/jpeg, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)120/1; image/jpeg, width=(int)640, height=(int)360, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)1285718/4945
0:00:00.529659282  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:820:gst_event_new_caps: creating caps event image/jpeg, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)60/1, colorimetry=(string)bt709, parsed=(boolean)true, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0.GstPad:src: caps = image/jpeg, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)60/1, colorimetry=(string)bt709, parsed=(boolean)true, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
0:00:00.530005899  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:3040:gst_v4l2_object_setup_pool:<v4l2jpegdec0:sink> accessing buffers via mode 2
0:00:00.530382015  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:557:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2jpegdec0:pool:sink> increasing minimum buffers to 2
0:00:00.530417639  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:570:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2jpegdec0:pool:sink> reducing maximum buffers to 32
0:00:00.530448139  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:581:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2jpegdec0:pool:sink> can't allocate, setting maximum to minimum
0:00:00.530514387  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1228:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:src> got 2 format(s):
0:00:00.530558386  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:src>   NT12
0:00:00.530594135  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:1232:gst_v4l2_object_fill_format_list:<v4l2jpegdec0:src>   NV12
0:00:00.530631384  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 WARN                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4400:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2jpegdec0:src> Failed to probe pixel aspect ratio with VIDIOC_CROPCAP: Invalid argument
0:00:00.531065125  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4458:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2jpegdec0:src> probed caps: video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12_10LE, width=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], height=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], interlace-mode=(string){ progressive, interleaved }, colorimetry=(string){ bt709 }; video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], height=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], interlace-mode=(string){ progressive, interleaved }, colorimetry=(string){ bt709 }
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/v4l2jpegdec:v4l2jpegdec0.GstPad:sink: caps = image/jpeg, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)60/1, colorimetry=(string)bt709, parsed=(boolean)true, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
0:00:00.554645211  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:3773:gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full:<v4l2src0:src> Set capture framerate to 60/1
0:00:00.554695960  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:3040:gst_v4l2_object_setup_pool:<v4l2src0:src> accessing buffers via mode 2
0:00:00.554897080  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:557:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2src0:pool:src> increasing minimum buffers to 2
0:00:00.554933955  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:570:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2src0:pool:src> reducing maximum buffers to 32
0:00:00.555070326  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:570:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_set_config:<v4l2src0:pool:src> reducing maximum buffers to 32
0:00:00.562723652  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 WARN          v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:813:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_start:<v4l2src0:pool:src> Uncertain or not enough buffers, enabling copy threshold
0:00:00.893169357  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:960:gst_v4l2src_create:<v4l2src0> sync to 0:00:00.016666666 out ts 0:00:00.057224030
0:00:00.893362602  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO               GST_EVENT gstevent.c:900:gst_event_new_segment: creating segment event time segment start=0:00:00.000000000, offset=0:00:00.000000000, stop=99:99:99.999999999, rate=1.000000, applied_rate=1.000000, flags=0x00, time=0:00:00.000000000, base=0:00:00.000000000, position 0:00:00.000000000, duration 99:99:99.999999999
0:00:00.893496849  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2962:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> marking pending DISCONT
0:00:00.940186158  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                    task gsttask.c:453:gst_task_set_lock: setting stream lock 0xaaaadc618700 on task 0xaaaadc61acb0
0:00:00.940323530  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                GST_PADS gstpad.c:6159:gst_pad_start_task:<v4l2jpegdec0:src> created task 0xaaaadc61acb0
0:00:00.941916119  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:960:gst_v4l2src_create:<v4l2src0> sync to 0:00:00.033333332 out ts 0:00:00.377275280
0:00:00.943203339  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:960:gst_v4l2src_create:<v4l2src0> sync to 0:00:00.049999998 out ts 0:00:00.393297280
0:00:00.944289190  2492 0xaaaadc620a80 INFO                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:960:gst_v4l2src_create:<v4l2src0> sync to 0:00:00.066666664 out ts 0:00:00.409296405
0:00:00.946186021  2492 0xaaaadc63fe80 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4458:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2jpegdec0:src> probed caps: video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12_10LE, framerate=(fraction)[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], height=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode=(string){ progressive, interleaved }; video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], height=(int)[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode=(string){ progressive, interleaved }
0:00:00.946338893  2492 0xaaaadc63fe80 ERROR           v4l2videodec gstv4l2videodec.c:656:gst_v4l2_video_dec_loop:<v4l2jpegdec0> not negotiated
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the h264 is the camera is sending a H264 output:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ! autovideosink
```

In case of a mjpeg stream:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! "image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080" ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```